# Converting from docx to markdown how to get rid of span underline in links?

Tags: pandoc, commonmark

Since a recent pandoc update (now I'm at 2.2.1) the links in a docx document are converted to `[<span class="underline">graphic novel hero</span>](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/1596432594/braipick-20)` adding a unneeded span to link labels. Is there any black magic (besides adding a `sed` call to the pipeline) to get rid of them and returning to pure commonmark?

The pandoc options I use are: `pandoc -f docx --atx-headers --wrap=none --extract-media=. -t commonmark-smart myFile.docx`

Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-t commonmark` the spans that the docx-reader generates are converted to raw HTML, so you could use:

```
pandoc -t commonmarkd-raw_html
```

Alternatively, use the markdown-writer, which is more flexible in terms of extensions (but as of 2018 not yet 100%-commonmark-compliant):

```
pandoc -t markdown-bracketed_spans-raw_html-native_spans
```

See the [MANUAL](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions) for more details.